# How to remove off-screen desktop gadget?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I was stupidly messing around with one of my desktop gadgets, and I ended up getting it stuck in the corner of the screen so much that the x-button won't show anymore. This is a big problem because the only solutions I could find is to click the x-button. Is there a way I could remove it from the desktop WITHOUT the x-button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Go to your start menu and type "gadget" in the start menu. Click the "view list of running gadgets". Then remove the gadget in question.

Also, you should be able to move the gadget back into the display by just clicking and dragging on part of it. (Unless that invokes some gadget function...)

Comment: THANK YOU! And I couldn't drag it back because I had it that far in the corner. But anyway, I didn't know it was that simple...

Comment: The thing is, you can never drag the gadget FULLY off the screen because in order to drag, you have to clik on it, and your mouse can't leave the screen (normally). So the pixel you dragged with always remains in screen. It might be a transparent pixel (like a corner outside of the default round clock widget), but still it's a pixel you can still click on.
Anyway... Glad I could help :)